# best practice common imports between base/child class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have import statements in base class:

base.py

```
import x
import y
import z

Class Base {
   ...
}
```

child.py

```
import x
import y
import z

Class Child(Base) {
   ...
}
```

How can I eliminate the redundancy of import x, y, z between the two classes?

Comment: Show us where you are using members of x,y, or x module in child and base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the best practice is considered to keep all imports explicit. Just the way they are right now.

But, you probably need to import `base` from `child` in order to inherit from `Base`. When you `import base`, `x`, `y`, `z` and `Base` will be available as `base.x`, `base.y`, `base.z` and `base.Base`.